# Method expects object to have 2 properties, but the object I have has it in an array?

Tags: ruby

There is a method that looks like:

```
def some_thing(user)
  x = user.age
  y = user.height
end
```

I have an object that looks like:

```
  x = other.info[0]
  y = other.info[1]
```

How could I pass this information to the method some_thing?

```
some_thing(other)
```

won't work as it doesn't have the properties exposed in that manner.

**Is it possible to do without modifying the classes and method parameters?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an anonymous `Struct` to create the properties and use `Array` splat to fill them:

```
some_thing(Struct.new(:age, :height).new(*other.info))
```

Comment: how would this work?  you are not referencing the array like other.info[0] and other.info[1] ?

Comment: `other.info` is an `Array`.  When you splat an `Array` by using the `*` as a prefix like `*other.info`, you can pass the elements of the array as arguments to a method.  The anonymous struct has an initialize where the first arg will be the age and the second arg with be the height.

Comment: This is the beauty of duck typing. :)